# How to make a logo css slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, carousel

I tried to make a logo slider using Owl carousel. But the carousel isn't appearing.

I want my carousel to look like this:
[image]

My html is:

```
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/c-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/h-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/a-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/am_logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/le-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/pan-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/i-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/b-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/s-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/so-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/ep-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/d-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/br-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/ap-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="resources/img/in-logo.png" alt="Owl Image"></div>
    </div>
```

My css is:

```
.owl-carousel .item{
    margin: 3px;
}

.owl-carousel .item img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

and in my html I included the script:

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({

      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

  });

});


</script>
```

I included the:

```
<script src="vendors/js/owl.carousel.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/owl.theme.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
```

How can I make the slider appear? Or is there an easier way to achieve this slider look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the owl carousel file after you have included JQuery like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/owl.theme.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```